# Will this banana tree grow in pot?

Tags: transplanting, repotting, banana

I have a small plot of soil with two banana trees. The banana tree in the picture will grow bananas if I leave it there.

I’m thinking of taking this 3-ft tree and moving it to a pot. Will it grow bananas even after I move it to a pot?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It will likely require a very large pot to grow fruit. When I have had bananas produce fruit , the plant has been over 12 feet tall.